# retrofit request body is adding double quotes in @Body parameter

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to serialize the request before sending it to the retrofit for webservice calls.

as i am serializing the request , i need to pass json string to retrofit calls in @Body paramenter and due to that 
   the generated json string results into following json string with the " (Double quotes in front and end ).

> "{\"access_token\":\"d80fa6bd6f78cc704104d61146c599bc94b82ca225349ee68762fc6c70d2dcf0\",\"fitness\":[{\"_id\":\"1d051bfe-df30-4fa0-808b-9d7300a608ab\",\"activity_id\":\"877284d3-4f36-4ec0-a536-11563207dc4d\",\"calories\":600.0,\"distance\":40.0,\"intensity\":\"100\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-07-18T12:56:43+00:00\",\"type\":\"Running\",\"utc_offset\":\"+05:30\"},{\"_id\":\"2004ff72-707d-489a-927e-4cdeed410095\",\"activity_id\":\"5ed7c90f-805e-4763-aa62-7f8126c84f06\",\"calories\":600.0,\"distance\":40.0,\"intensity\":\"100\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-07-18T12:56:43+00:00\",\"type\":\"Running\",\"utc_offset\":\"+05:30\"}]}"

as there are double quotes the third party api is unable to parse it successfully.

here is my reqeust serializer code

```
 public class RequestSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Request<?>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Request<?> request, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

        JsonObject jsonObject =  new GsonBuilder().create().toJsonTree(request,Request.class).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement requestList = jsonObject.get("requestList");
        jsonObject.remove("requestList");
        jsonObject.add("fitness",requestList);
        return jsonObject;

    }
 }
```

code to call retrofit webservice

```
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Request.class, new RequestSerializer());
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    String data = gson.toJson(request);

    Flowable<Response> fitnessFlowable = new WebRequest().getRemoteClient().create(FitnessApi.class).postFitnessData("5b238abb4d3590001d9b94a8",data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using objects eliminates string quoting request in POST @Body,
example as my working code:

```
class Data{
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String access_token;

    public String getAccess_token() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    // Other field defined here
}

@Keep
class Result{
    @SerializedName("rc") int rc;
}

@Keep
interface APIFitness{
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("api/save/")
    Observable<Result> Save(@Body Data data);

    //More methods..
}
```

using

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIFitness service = retrofit.create(APIFitness.class);
    Data data = new Data();
    authCode.setAccess_token(token);

    service.Save(data)
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
           .subscribe( data -> { } )
```